# Stacking divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stack these divs side by side - left and right. The right stack of divs won't clear. Should I float the left stack to left and the same with the right stack or do left and right floats?

I'm trying to emulate this, I'm trying to make a table but with divs. 
http://www.weareint.io/

Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/zeegn9cn/

```css
 * {
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
 }
 #sections {
   /*--LEFT SECTION COLUMNS--*/
   width: 1000px;
   height: 400px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background: red;
 }
 .sectionLfirst {
   width: 500px;
   background: orange;
 }
 .sectionLsecond {
   width: 500px;
   background: skyblue;
 }
 .sectionLthird {
   width: 500px;
   background: Indigo;
   clear: both;
 }
 .sectionRfirst {
   /*--RIGHT SECTION COLUMNS--*/
   float: right;
   width: 500px;
   background: orange;
   clear: both;
 }
 .sectionRsecond {
   float: right;
   width: 500px;
   background: skyblue;
   clear: both;
 }
 .sectionRthird {
   float: right;
   width: 500px;
   background: Indigo;
   clear: both;
 }
```

```html
<!--LEFT SECTION COLUMNS-->
<div id="sections">
  <div class="sectionLfirst">
    <h3>fdkfjdkfj</h3>
    <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sectionLsecond">
    <h3>fdkfjdkfj</h3>
    <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sectionLthird">
    <h3>fdkfjdkfj</h3>
    <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
  </div>

  <!--LEFT SECTION COLUMNS-->
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="sectionRfirst">
    <h3>1fdkfjdkfj</h3>
    <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sectionRsecond">
    <h3>2fdkfjdkfj</h3>
    <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sectionRthird">
    <h3>3fdkfjdkfj</h3>
    <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: which bit of that link are you trying to emulate? the whole site?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zeegn9cn/15/

Comment: When you enter the site, click on the x on the top right. Theres a header, section with text align and then below, a table displayed. You can roll over them like buttons. I'm trying to emulate that, but with divs.

Answer (score 3):

you could wrap them in divs and float them like this:

```css
*{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
#sections{   /*--LEFT SECTION COLUMNS--*/
  width:1000px;
  height:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:red;
}
.sectionLfirst{
  width:500px;
  background:orange;
}
.sectionLsecond{
  width:500px;
  background:skyblue;
}
.sectionLthird{
  width:500px;
  background:Indigo;
  clear:both;
}  
  .sectionRfirst{  /*--RIGHT SECTION COLUMNS--*/
  float:right; 
  width:500px;
  background:orange;
  clear:both;
}
.sectionRsecond{
  float:right;
  width:500px;
  background:skyblue;
  clear:both;
  
}
.sectionRthird{
  float:right;
  width:500px;
  background:Indigo;
  clear:both;
}
.left {
    float: left;    
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!--LEFT SECTION COLUMNS--> 
<div id="sections">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="sectionLfirst">
            <h3>fdkfjdkfj</h3>
            <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sectionLsecond">
            <h3>fdkfjdkfj</h3>
            <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sectionLthird">
            <h3>fdkfjdkfj</h3>
            <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--LEFT SECTION COLUMNS--> 
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="sectionRfirst">
            <h3>1fdkfjdkfj</h3>
            <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sectionRsecond">
            <h3>2fdkfjdkfj</h3>
            <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sectionRthird">
            <h3>3fdkfjdkfj</h3>
            <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: I like this answer best out of the three posted at this time, The column divs allow you to better control the layout of just one column as opposed to dealing with having to float all the divs. However, if you're looking for a more "grid" based system, the answer below is your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

If you control the html you could rearrange the html and float all the elements to the left.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#sections {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
}
#sections > div {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
}
.sectionLfirst {
    background: orange;
}
.sectionLsecond {
    background: skyblue;
}
.sectionLthird {
    background: indigo;
}
.sectionRfirst {
    background: orange;
}
.sectionRsecond {
    background: skyblue;
}
.sectionRthird {
    background: indigo;
}
```

```html
<div id="sections">
    <div class="sectionLfirst">
        <h3>fdkfjdkfj</h3>
        <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionRfirst">
        <h3>1fdkfjdkfj</h3>
        <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionLsecond">
        <h3>fdkfjdkfj</h3>
        <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionRsecond">
        <h3>2fdkfjdkfj</h3>
        <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionLthird">
        <h3>fdkfjdkfj</h3>
        <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionRthird">
        <h3>3fdkfjdkfj</h3>
        <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going about this wrong. Don't float them, that's not what your trying to achieve here.

Wrap the three div's and give the wrapper `align-row` (see code for `.align`) and give the parent `align-table` (see your `#sections`).

This will also allow you to have a truly responsive layout if you remove the width of `#sections` because of the CSS Rule `table-layout: fixed;` this will mean the side by side elements will site side by side and also change width automatically and will not disrupt the flow of content.

check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeegn9cn/9/)

---

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#sections {
  /*--LEFT SECTION COLUMNS--*/
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.align {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
.sectionLfirst {
  width: 500px;
  background: orange;
}
.sectionLsecond {
  background: skyblue;
}
.sectionLthird {
  background: Indigo;
}
.sectionRfirst {
  /*--RIGHT SECTION COLUMNS--*/
  background: orange;
}
.sectionRsecond {
  background: skyblue;
}
.sectionRthird {
  background: Indigo;
}
```

```html
<!--LEFT SECTION COLUMNS-->
<div id="sections">
  <div class="align">
    <div class="sectionLfirst">
      <h3>fdkfjdkfj</h3>

      <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionLsecond">
      <h3>fdkfjdkfj</h3>

      <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionLthird">
      <h3>fdkfjdkfj</h3>

      <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--LEFT SECTION COLUMNS-->
  <div class="align">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="sectionRfirst">
      <h3>1fdkfjdkfj</h3>

      <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionRsecond">
      <h3>2fdkfjdkfj</h3>

      <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionRthird">
      <h3>3fdkfjdkfj</h3>

      <p>fdlfkdlkfldkfdlkfdl</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why use table alignment on a div when you can just float them? As far as responsiveness goes you can make them 50% width and the wrapper 100% width if you desire that effect but for mobile you would likely want to move the right column below, in which case the table layout is a pain

Comment: @Zach Float is just not a good solution. I'm not going to get into the ins and out's of it because of opinionated debate on SO. but basically Float is used for when you want to move something like an image and break the flow so that say text can wrap it. This will not break document flow and damage wrapper height's. Float is not really for positioning elements like this. It's an abused and missused rule

Comment: Just for curiosity sake what about display:inline-block on the left and right divs? That would work as well. I just assumed that it was really no different than a float in the end besides for the wrapper height issue but that is easily fixed with a clear at the bottom. I just hate the inflexibility of table layouts, especially on mobile

Comment: @Zach 2 main reasons for display inline block. display inline block is not designed for elements to sit shoulder to shoulder it wants a gap inbetween. also you once again need to set the width of it. Also there is no inflexibility in the css table you most likely just don't know the rule to use them. CSS Tables offer more mobile flexbility then any other css rule (flex-box's & coumns excluded because of there lack of support in dtop browsers) because you can rearrange them at will for instance you could move the left most element which would natural be on top to the bottom when going to mobile

Comment: @DCdaz  What if I want to put a border style around it like I tried here. This is horrendous ---> https://jsfiddle.net/3bmbxcvb/ using display table - the code you gave me  fiddle this the effect I'm trying to get here, i used floats and no display table --> https://jsfiddle.net/06guryqo/

Comment: @ChrisBrennan Hi chris you had messed up your html you where missing a end div tag look here https://jsfiddle.net/3bmbxcvb/2/

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way instead.  It's cleaner.

https://jsfiddle.net/zeegn9cn/13/

```
#leftSections {
    float:left;
}
#rightSections {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I often wondered how this could be done easily. I started a new job recently, and found out I should have been using Bootstrap (there are other options too).

It really conveniently let's you make a row or three evenly sized columns, for instance, among many other excellent features.

You can do all this stuff by hand, but I think it's actually better to learn industry standards like Bootstrap that will save you a lot of time. I realize this doesn't directly answer your html/css question, but I wish someone had told me this earlier.

Here's [Bootstrap's](http://getbootstrap.com/) main website.

[This](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html) page will show you the basics of making these columns.

Also note, Bootstrap is excellent for making responsive webpages, meaning it will easily re-size items for you on different device sizes, or if you change the window size.

For instance, if you want to make a gird of divs two columns wide, and three rows tall, you can use the following html, if using Bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h1>Section 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h1>Section 4</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h1>Section 5</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h1>Section 6</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it is much cleaner, and doesn't require you to hand write any css. It's a powerful tool to eliminate many low level layout concerns.

Comment: This is not an answer and Bootstrap is a framework that contains css it is not a solution to this problem.

Comment: Bootstrap is a little overkill for a simple solution.

Comment: You're right, it's not a direct solution, which I said in my answer. It is an alternate method if what he's actually interested in is getting the result he wants, rather than knowing how to achieve it specifically with bare-bones html and css. I'm just offering what I consider a helpful alternative. I agree bootstrap could be overkill, but it makes it a lot more reasonable to get really good results like the example OP linked. I guarantee that page isn't written in straight html and css. As I said, not a direct solution, but I wish someone had told me about bootstrap years ago.

Comment: I am neither critiquing nor requesting clarification. I am suggesting a solution that is not the solution they are thinking of, and not fully enumerating that solution. I agree I'm not exactly answering OP's question.

Comment: Updated to have actual example html. I still think it's valid to suggest a helpful technology that trivializes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zeegn9cn/14/

Wrap them and float the wraps and remove the floats on the individual divs

CSS

```
    *{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
#sections{   /*--LEFT SECTION COLUMNS--*/
  width:1000px;
  height:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:red;
}

.left {
    width:500px;
    float:left;
}

.right {
    width:500px;
    float:right;
}
.sectionLfirst{
  width:500px;
  background:orange;
}
.sectionLsecond{
  width:500px;
  background:skyblue;
}
.sectionLthird{
  width:500px;
  background:Indigo;
}  
  .sectionRfirst{  /*--RIGHT SECTION COLUMNS--*/ 
  width:500px;
  background:orange;
}
.sectionRsecond{
  width:500px;
  background:skyblue;

}
.sectionRthird{
  width:500px;
  background:Indigo;
}
```

EDIT

If you want it responsive put a max width of 100% on the wrapper and make the inside percentage width. However I would advise that you move the column below by making the left and right section 100% width on mobile. Here is the fiddle for a responsive version without moving the column below https://jsfiddle.net/zeegn9cn/17/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using floats is the right approach for building a site like this. make use of `display:inline-block` or `display:table` that way you can keep columns next to each other but keep them centered on the page:

this way if you make the correct css decisions, you can have a lot of flexibility and reusability with classes. and you can nest other elements within the columns to make a table-like structure. Also, this is responsive, no static widths/heights on your divs.

you can also define media queries to decide what to do when the screen size gets too small. Perhaps, mark all columns as `display:block` so they take up the entire width of the window

see this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/y3uprrow/1/

Comment: Agreed. Float is far removed from this use.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/zeegn9cn/15/

```
/*--ADDED--*/
#sections-inner{
    display:inline-block;
    verticle-alignment:top;
}
```

Comment: I need to work more with inline-blocks. I rarely use them. Still a beginner.  Thanks.